# Built a gem but when tried it gives an error that command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Hi I have built a CLI Ruby gem.

If i try to run it through git repo, it works perfectly fine. But if I try to install a gem and run it, it gives me an error that command not found.

Error message..

```
 popular_deals                                                                                                                                                          
-su: popular_deals: command not found
```

A friend of mine also tried, he got this error message

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      colorize (>= 0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
/Users/M/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/popular_deals-0.2.0/bin/popular-deals:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- popular_deals (LoadError)
    from /Users/M/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/popular_deals-0.2.0/bin/popular-deals:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/M/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/popular-deals:23:in `load'
    from /Users/M/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/popular-deals:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/M/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/M/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Here is a link of my gem..

https://rubygems.org/gems/popular_deals

Here is a link of github repo..

https://github.com/HimaChitalia/popular-deals-from-slickdeals.net-cli

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Post the error message from your log please

Comment: Try prepending `bundle exec` to what you are trying to invoke from the command line.

Comment: @bkunzi01 Thank you for your suggestion. I have improved my question.

Comment: @David S. Thank you for your suggestion. It gives me "Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory" error.

Comment: Did you push all your changes to RubyGems as a new version? And maybe try making the scripts executables (`chmod a+x`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by doing the following. I think that in your original answer you were executing `popular_deals`, when the command is actually `popular-deals` and not the same as the name of the gem!

```
mkdir deals_test
cd deals_test
# Contents shown below
touch Gemfile
bundle
bundle exec popular-deals
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'popular_deals'
```

I'm using MRI 2.3.3

Comment: You are right. Initially, I also tried popular-deals but didn't work. Maybe because I had required 'pry'. After I removed it, it started working. I am really not sure about how it started working as I tried many different things. But yes, now it works with popular-deals. Thank you so much for your help!